# Is there any method to download tables from tableau for further using?

Tags: excel-formula, tableau-api, google-analytics-api, tableau-desktop, tableau-cloud

how can i download this table using tableau to use it by excel sheet and how can i export any merged tables to use its data

[image]

i tried to download only dashboard but to do it and send to someone else he has to have tableau application while not all peopole have.
i merged tables from excel and looking to use union to get the filtered data using tableau while i can not have the net result i want by downloading

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.